# Django: How can I add weight/ordering to a many to many relationship?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm having Pages with TextBlocks on them. Text Blocks may appear on different pages, pages may have several text blocks on them. Every page may have these blocks in an ordering of it's own. 
 This can be solved by using a separate *through* parameter. Like so:

```
class TextBlock(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()

class Page(models.Model):
    textblocks = models.ManyToManyField(TextBlock, through=OrderedTextBlock)

class OrderedTextBlock(models.Model):
    text_block = models.ForeignKey(TextBlock)
    product_page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    weight = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('weight',)
```

But I'm not very enthousiastic about the violations of DRY for my app. (There's a lot of ordered ManyToMany relations). Is there a recommended way to go about this?

Edit: typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, perhaps, create your own [Custom Field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#howto-custom-model-fields) - OrderedManyToManyField, perhaps, as a [subclass](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#writing-a-field-subclass) of ManyToManyField.

Or, if that doesn't look ideal you could use your existing approach, creating multiple 'through' models, but [subclass them](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/models/#id5) from each other to adhere to DRY as best you can

```
class OrderedM2M(models.Model):
    weight = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('weight',)
        abstract = True

class OrderedTextBlock(OrderedM2M):
    text_block = models.ForeignKey(TextBlock)
    product_page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
```

Comment: The custom field is a great idea that pointed me in this direction:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-sortedm2m/0.2.0

Answer (score 0):

[pycruft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346573/pycruft)'s answer is perfect. And Your sortedm2m is great. Can I suggest a mod to it, where the weighted sorting also takes in an M2M, so that there's a different weight system for each given User model, or perhaps Subreddit (now called a Community, on my site I call them Spaces - because it opens a space for discussion around a topic, as the community element is detached from the IRL version of a community which needs a literal place of establishment like a Church or Club or Group Homestead etc. but nowadays they use it to refer to say "the LGBT" community etc.).

Ideally I would do M2M2M, so each Post gets a weight for each Space for each User. Allowing us to define a customisable, updating, metric so that based on the relative interest displayed in the relative section we can create a mechanism for Suggested Posts on a section by section basis.

And then obviously we would have many of these too, so there would also be adjectives/modifiers added to the word "Suggested" to the point of "Novelty Suggested" (something that impacts their creativity), "Unique Suggested" (something that stands out to them), "Unheard of Suggested" (something they haven't heard of), "Mind-Opening Suggested" (on a topic they disagree with but might change their mind), "Mind-Expanding Suggested" (information that adds novelty to the ideas they've already created),

as well as for other modifiers for other default sorts like instead of just "New"/"Recent" we would have "Unheard of New" (things that are both new and haven't been seen much), etc. etc.

As well as other things like "Super Spreader" (things that are new, highly liked but lowly commented on), "Longtime Fantasy" (things based on what they most often say, is almost never talked about by others, and yet was long ago mentioned, somewhere someplace sometime), and an alternative to this would be "Longlived Fantasy" (things based on what they have said at some point, but is super popular when said by the right person).

And then things for User sorting to, not just Post sorting, as the M2M2M2M will need to be applied to each M2M. So "Likely to Like" (people who's posts you're likely to like), "Likely to Hunt" (people you're going to rage at), "Likely to Chase" (people you may or may not like, but you're going to go through all their stuff from now on), "Likely to Traceback" (people who's history of Posts (could be modified further to include history of Votes, history of Comments) you're likely to want to go through)...

The list goes on. Got to be prepared for some super-comp and super-AI. And it could be then user-modifiable so when they go through any of these weighted-sortings that use AI, they could teach us about how we did by selecting to remove certain certain things from a given sort (and then shift it to another one, because there'll be room for hating hate and loving love - people's moods change, as do their desires for different moods).

Ohp. I just took a closer look at your django-sortedm2m. That kinda solves a lot of this. Can you add another option for including a given "weight" as per this question and answer, or should I fork and go for that. ie.

```
gallery = Gallery.objects.create(name='Photos ordered by name')
for photo in Photo.objects.order_by('name'):
    weight = AI_Self_Suggester_Output(photo)
    gallery.photos.add(photo, weight)
```